# Query by key or author

Tags: wp-query, search

So right now my query looks like this:

```
$allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1");
```

I understand what this query does and it works, but not I want to add the ability to query posts by `$s` OR by multiple authors. I don't exclusively want posts that match the search or posts by the list of authors, but I want both together.

I want to build the argument according to [this](https://gist.github.com/luetkemj/2023628).

This is what I have so far:

```
$args = array (
    'author' => '1,2,3,4,5',
    's' => $s,
    'posts_per_page' => -1 
);

$allsearch = &new WP_Query($args);
```

However I'm pretty sure that this query only returns posts that or both by the listed authors and match the search key.

All suggestions or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Remember that when you post code as exemple make it a valid PHP code before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use the `&new WP_Query` just `new WP_Query`.

The following code will resolve your problem.

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'q166788_search_modify', 10, 2 );

function q166788_search_modify( $sql, $query ){
    // Only if our variable is true we do the black magic
    if ( ! isset( $query->query_vars['search_conditional_toggle'] ) || $query->query_vars['search_conditional_toggle'] !== true ){
        return $sql;
    }

    return preg_replace('/AND/', 'OR', $sql, 1 );
}

// The actual search
    $s = 'bord';

    $args = array (
        'author' => '1,2,3,4,5',
        's' => $s,
        'search_conditional_toggle' => true, // Make the black magic happen
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $allsearch = new WP_Query( $args );

    var_dump( $allsearch );
```

Comment: IT doesn't return any articles by the authors. It just returns articles related to the search. Also what's the point of the printer() and adding it as an action?

Comment: That's just a way of doing an exemple the printer, and there was a bug on my code I found and Fixed it.

Comment: Just to clarify: I want either posts that have the keyword in their content, or posts by the author. Obviously, the posts by the author don't have to have the keyword in them. I"m not sure that this does that right? This just changes all instance of `AND` to `OR` right?

Comment: No, what I did there was changing the first instance of the `AND` to a `OR` for the search query; Which will make the SQL query for either the Author OR Search

Comment: So if it's not working, then there might be a problem with the author value? I made sure it was corect

Comment: With the changes I did on the `q166788_search_modify` method it still doesn't work? It did on my local testing.

Comment: It does work actually. How would you specify to search for posts only, not uploads, or other things. Right now it returns uploads, pages, or anything created under the user. I just want posts.

Comment: I was trying it here, it is harder then it seems, because there is too much clauses. But want you want is the search to be `( wp_posts.post_author IN (1,2,3,4,5) OR (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%bord%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%bord%'))) )` instead of `wp_posts.post_author IN (1,2,3,4,5) OR (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%bord%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%bord%')))`; I have yet to figure out a way to do it.

Comment: By the way, thank you for helping me out so much. It's almost like you're following my questions... but I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18243/discussion-between-wold-and-bordoni).